# unable to properly register x64 COM dll on windows 7 x64

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, com

I have a C++ ATL COM DLL that was originally built for x86, dll is being consumed by .NET 4.0 app built for x86, everything works fine.

After recompiling the COM dll for x64, and then registering it using `c:\windows\system32\regsvr32` (after un-reg the x86 dll), I'm unable to see the COM DLL in Visual Studio Add Reference window, I exported the reg keys for HKCR and HKLM\Softwares with the x64 and then x86 version of the dll registered, and no keys are missing, the respective keys are pointing to the correct dll location.

Additionally, after registering x64 dll, I am able to add reference to dll by navigating to the folder where file is, and selecting it, but it still fails to execute (.net assembly is set to x64) with following error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory  for component with CLSID
>   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-A797AD238051} failed due to the followi ng
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASS NOTREG)).    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolea n noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurity Check)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boo lean fillCache)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipVisibil ityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
>   fillCache)    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
>   nonPublic)

I've spent considerable amount of time searching online, but haven't found anything remotely close, anyone seen anything like this, or any debugging tool I can perhaps use?

I don't own the dll by the way, the person that owns it, can see the x64 dll once built on the machine, but have tried on 2 other machines, and it didn't work on either one.

Comment: Not seeing the component in the dialog is entirely normal, VS is a 32-bit process so can only see 32-bit COM servers.  Don't unregister your x86 version.  I can't follow the rest of it.

Comment: One of the challenges of x64 is the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx) which helps - sometimes too much.  It's possible one registration is trampling on the other.  A good tool for many situations is SysInternals [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  Monitor the registry while reproducing the problem and you can see what registry entries are really being read.

Comment: I'd also suggest you simplify things by getting InteropServices out of the picture.  Build simple 32-bit and 64-bit test clients in C++. Get those working first before trying to call your COM object from managed code.

Comment: @FrankBoyne I'll give procmon a shot, didn't think of it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure that behavior is normal, I'm not very experienced with COM, but I did build a test x64 C++ COM DLL and was able to see it in the add reference window in VS, and was also able to invoke it in my x64 .NET app.  Also, the x64 and x86 have the same typelib and clsid guid, wouldn't that cause a problem if I don't unreg the x86 library?  I did try this approach but I get AccessViolationException, not even multithreading anything at all, but of course the dll works perfectly on the dll developer's machine

Comment: If you have the TLB file from the COM, you can use it to register it in your project.

@Jason, I found that some COM projects register in both the 64 and 32 bit portion of the registry while others don't.  I have posted a question related to this here but did not get answers yet, however you can see what I discovered so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998427/c-odl-com-x64-not-visible-in-visual-studio-no-entry-in-the-32-bits-windows-re

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, and I would need more information to troubleshoot fully.  However, I might be able to provide some tips for anyone running across the same issue.

Given that you are using `regsvr32`, the DLL is using something called [self-registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694515(v=vs.85).aspx).  This means that the DLL is handling its own addition to the Windows registry in an exported function called [DllRegisterServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162(v=vs.85).aspx).  As you seem to have discovered, the registry entries differ between x86 and x64, but that is not necessarily your core issue here.    You can, and often should, have both x86 and x64 type libraries registered.

One manner of checking how a specific type library is registered is the [oleview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693754(v=vs.85).aspx) tool.  The same information is in the registry, but this tool can be a little friendlier.  The tool should be in the path set from the Visual Studio command prompt.  It sounds like the error is about a class with a given GUID, which you can check from Object Classes -> All Objects in the tree:

[image: Finding a class in the tree]

If you do happen to have the class (you may have to re-register the x86 version to check), you can find information on the COM interfaces the class implements by expanding the entry for the GUID you just found.  If there is a type library, it should say so.  Notice that there can be both `win32` and `win64` entries for paths in the TypeLib info:

[image: Example of interface with both win32 and win64 paths]

Without further information, it is difficult to say, but I would guess that something is wrong with the self-registration and/or type library for x64.  Incidentally, for libraries you plan to release, you might not rely on self-registration anyway -- installer packages can and should create registry entries themselves.  If you do have further information, I could try providing more specifics.